# Mongo: Used $addToSet without $each. How to remove arrays?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object like so:

```
object: {
    ids: [ ObjectId('1...'), ObjectId('2...')]
}
```

And I want to add a few elements to the `ids` array:

```
[ObjectId('3...'), ObjectId('4...')]]
```

Instead of doing that properly:

```
Object.update({ _id: someId }, 
    { 
      $addToSet: { ids: { $each: [ObjectId('3...'), ObjectId('4...')]]} 
    }
);
```

I unintentionally did a bad thing:

```
Object.update({ _id: someId }, 
    { 
      $addToSet: { ids: [ObjectId('3...'), ObjectId('4...')]] }
    }
);
```

Sticking me now with an object that looks like:

```
{
  ids: [ ObjectId('1...'), ObjectId('2...'), [ObjectId('3...'), ObjectId('4...')]]
}
```

So obviously, that's a problem. I tried some programmatic solutions such as checking if the element was an array `(if Array.isArray(elem))`, but it looked like mongoose was flattening the results on query.

What is a good way to reverse this problem? Or in other terms, how do I flatten the array?

Comment: could you explain what you exactly want?

Comment: Use $pull. Something like `db.colname.update(
    { },
    { $pull: { ids: { $type: "array" } } }
)`

Comment: Updated question

Comment: You have to remove the values and insert the values with $each again. Is that what you are looking for ? The last comment to remove the array value.

Comment: I gave your pull a try, and found that while it would say 'Updated x records' that it did not actually